# Stuck with the installation of React.js

Tags: reactjs

While installing React.js, I am getting stuck here. I've referred to the previous questions regarding the same. But couldn't find a solution. Even after uninstalling and reinstalling, I am unable to solve this issue. Also, I am not getting an index.js file after the installation. Someone guide me.

[image: Here is a screen capture]

Comment: Your CRA installation was not success as well. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the image, you didn't go to the `todo` directory.

```
npx create-react-app todo

cd todo

npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Open an completly empty folder in a terminal and type `npx create-react-app .`